# How to enforce DB2 users to login using SSL certificate

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a db2 hosted instance (a db2 running on a Linux box with a public ip address). I want the users to only be able to connect to the DB2 using a SSL certificate and disable login using username/password on port 50000. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [DB2COMM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.regvars.doc/doc/r0005660.html#r0005660__C_DB2COMM) registry variable. It determines what communication managers are started. It is set to `TCPIP` if only unencrypted communication is enabled, `TCPIP,SSL` if both, and you can set it to only `SSL`. In that case only encrypted communication is allowed.

Make sure to test SSL communication thoroughly before disabling regular connections. [The SSL setup itself is described in the Db2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0025241.html).

Comment: So how can i change the value of DB2COMM in a linux server?

Comment: DB2COMM is changed on linux the same way as on the other plattforms - check out the db2set command: i.e. db2set DB2COMM=SSL

Comment: That's described with details in the linked documentation. All the steps to set up SSL and enable the communication manager.